# Why is my second gauge chart not being rendered?

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, javascript, lightning-experience, html

I'm trying to clone the Target Gauge Chart (left) to create the Target Spex Gauge Chart (right), but this is happening:

Even if/when `isTargetSpexInitialized` is true, the right graph is not displayed. It seems that the method loadChart() of this one is not running.

What can we do?

[image]

**gaugeChart.html**

```
<template>
  <lightning-card title="Chart for Targets" icon-name="utility:chart">
    
    <!-- Target Gauge Chart -->
    <div style="text-align: center; display:inline-block;">
      <div if:false={isChartJsInitialized}>
          <span class="slds-assistive-text">warning</span>
          <div style="margin-bottom: 1em;">
            <p class="slds-badge slds-theme_warning" style="font-size: 15px;">Gauge chart not loaded yet. Target is not filled out.</p>
          </div>
        <span if:true={sumOppsNotZero} class="slds-badge slds-theme_success" style="font-size: 14px;">Sum of Opps: {currencyEvt} {sumOpps}</span>
      </div>
      <div if:true={isChartJsInitialized}>
        <div style="margin-bottom: 1.5em;">
          <p style="font-size: 15px;" class="slds-badge">Target: {currencyEvt} {totalTarget}</p>
        </div>
        <canvas id="gaugechart" lwc:dom="manual"></canvas>
        <div if:true={chartInfo} id="percentage" style="font-size: 15px">
          {chartInfo}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Target Spex Gauge Chart -->
    <div style="text-align: left; display:inline-block;">
      <div if:false={isTargetSpexInitialized}>
          <span class="slds-assistive-text">warning</span>
          <div style="margin-bottom: 1em;">
            <p class="slds-badge slds-theme_warning" style="font-size: 15px;">Gauge chart not loaded yet. Target is not filled out.</p>
          </div>
        <span if:true={sumOppsNotZero} class="slds-badge slds-theme_success" style="font-size: 14px;">Sum of Opps: {currencyEvt} {sumOpps}</span>
      </div>
      <div id="spex" if:true={isTargetSpexInitialized}>
        <div style="margin-bottom: 1.5em;">
          <p style="font-size: 15px;" class="slds-badge">Target Spex: {currencyEvt} {totalTarget}</p>
        </div>
        <canvas lwc:dom="manual"></canvas>
        <div if:true={chartInfo} style="font-size: 15px">
          {chartInfo}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </lightning-card>
</template>
```

**gaugeChart.js (Target Gauge Chart)**:

```
/* eslint-disable no-undef */
/* eslint-disable @lwc/lwc/no-api-reassignments */
/* eslint-disable @lwc/lwc/no-dupe-class-members */
import { LightningElement, track, api, wire } from "lwc";
import gaugechart from "@salesforce/resourceUrl/bernii_gauge";
import { loadScript } from "lightning/platformResourceLoader";
import { ShowToastEvent } from "lightning/platformShowToastEvent";
import getTarget from "@salesforce/apex/GaugeChartController.getTarget";
import { getRecord } from "lightning/uiRecordApi";
// import RecurrenceInterval from "@salesforce/schema/Task.RecurrenceInterval";

export default class GaugeChart extends LightningElement {
  @track isChartJsInitialized = false;
  @track targetEvt;
  @api targetEvent = 0;
  @track amount = 0;
  @api currency;
  @api error;
  @api recordId;
  chartInfo;
  percentage = 0;
  sumOpps = 0;
  currencyEvt;
  totalTarget = 0;
  sumOppsNotZero = false;

  connectedCallback() {
    this.handleGetTarget();
  }

  @wire(getRecord, { recordId: "$recordId", fields: ["Event__c.Target__c"] })
  getTargetRecord({ data, error }) {
    if (data) {
      this.targetEvt = data.fields.Target__c.value;
      console.log("targetEvt: ", this.targetEvt);
      this.loadChart();
    } else if (error) {
      console.error("ERROR => ", JSON.stringify(error));
    }
  }

  handleGetTarget() {
    getTarget({ eventId: this.recordId })
      .then((result) => {
        console.log("retorno");
        this.targetEvt = result.target;
        this.amount = result.sumAmount;
        console.log("amount: ", this.amount);
        this.currency = result.currencyEvt;
        console.log("currency: ", this.currency);
        this.error = undefined;
        this.loadChart();
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        this.targetEvent = undefined;
        this.error = error;
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

  config = {
    generateGradient: true,
    pointer: {
      length: 0.5,
      strokeWidth: 0.05,
      iconScale: 1.0
    },
    // static labels
    staticLabels: {
      font: "14px sans-serif",
      labels: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      fractionDigits: 0
    },
    // static zones
    staticZones: [
      { strokeStyle: "red", min: 0, max: 0 },
      { strokeStyle: "orange", min: 0, max: 0 },
      { strokeStyle: "yellow", min: 0, max: 0 },
      { strokeStyle: "green", min: 0, max: 0 }
    ],
    // the span of the gauge arc
    angle: 0,
    // line thickness
    lineWidth: 0.2,
    // radius scale
    radiusScale: 1,
    // font size
    fontSize: 40,
    // if false, max value increases automatically if value > maxValue
    limitMax: false,
    // if true, the min value of the gauge will be fixed
    limitMin: true,
    // High resolution support
    highDpiSupport: true
  };

  loadChart() {
    console.log("loadChart() called");

    if (this.targetEvt == null || this.targetEvt === 0) {
      console.log("condition is true.");
      this.targetEvt = 0;
      if (this.amount > 0) {
        this.sumOppsNotZero = true;
        this.currencyEvt = this.currency;
        this.sumOpps = this.amount.toLocaleString("en-GB");
      }
      this.isChartJsInitialized = false;
      return;
    }
    
    this.isChartJsInitialized = true;
   
    this.totalTarget = this.targetEvt.toLocaleString("en-GB");
    this.currencyEvt = this.currency;

    // staticLabels
    this.config.staticLabels.labels[1] = this.targetEvt / 4;
    
    this.config.staticLabels.labels[2] = this.targetEvt / 2;
    this.config.staticLabels.labels[3] = (this.targetEvt * 3) / 4;
    this.config.staticLabels.labels[4] = this.targetEvt;

    // staticZones
    this.config.staticZones[0].max = this.targetEvt / 4;

    this.config.staticZones[1].min = this.targetEvt / 4 + 1;
    this.config.staticZones[1].max = this.targetEvt / 2;

    this.config.staticZones[2].min = this.targetEvt / 2 + 1;
    this.config.staticZones[2].max = (this.targetEvt * 3) / 4;

    this.config.staticZones[3].min = (this.targetEvt * 3) / 4 + 1;
    this.config.staticZones[3].max = this.targetEvt;

    Promise.all([loadScript(this, gaugechart)])
      .then(() => {
        let target = this.template.querySelector("canvas");
        Gauge.prototype.paddingBottom = 0.3;
        let gauge = new Gauge(target).setOptions(this.config);
        console.log(gauge);
        gauge.maxValue = this.targetEvt;
        gauge.setMinValue(0);
        gauge.animationSpeed = 32;
        gauge.set(this.amount);
        if (this.amount > this.targetEvt) {
          // this.config.staticLabels.labels[4] = this.amount;
          this.config.staticZones[3].max = this.amount;
        }
        this.percentage = ((this.amount / this.targetEvt) * 100).toFixed(1);
        this.chartInfo = `${this.currency} ${gauge.value.toLocaleString(
          "en-GB"
        )} (${this.percentage}%)`;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        this.dispatchEvent(
          new ShowToastEvent({
            title: "Error loading gauge.js",
            message: error.message,
            variant: "error"
          })
        );
      });
  }
}
```

**targetSpex.js**

```
/* eslint-disable no-undef */
/* eslint-disable @lwc/lwc/no-api-reassignments */
/* eslint-disable @lwc/lwc/no-dupe-class-members */
import { LightningElement, track, api, wire } from "lwc";
import gaugechart from "@salesforce/resourceUrl/bernii_gauge";
import { loadScript } from "lightning/platformResourceLoader";
import { ShowToastEvent } from "lightning/platformShowToastEvent";
import getTarget from "@salesforce/apex/GaugeChartController.getTarget";
import { getRecord } from "lightning/uiRecordApi";
// import RecurrenceInterval from "@salesforce/schema/Task.RecurrenceInterval";

export default class GaugeChart extends LightningElement {
  @track isTargetSpexInitialized = false;
  @track targetEvt;
  @api targetEvent = 0;
  @track amount = 0;
  @api currency;
  @api error;
  @api recordId;
  chartInfo;
  percentage = 0;
  sumOpps = 0;
  currencyEvt;
  totalTarget = 0;
  sumOppsNotZero = false;

  connectedCallback() {
    this.handleGetTarget();
  }

  @wire(getRecord, { recordId: "$recordId", fields: ["Event__c.Target__c"] })
  getTargetRecord({ data, error }) {
    if (data) {
      this.targetEvt = data.fields.Target__c.value;
      console.log("targetEvt: ", this.targetEvt);
      this.loadChart();
    } else if (error) {
      console.error("ERROR => ", JSON.stringify(error));
    }
  }

  handleGetTarget() {
    getTarget({ eventId: this.recordId })
      .then((result) => {
        console.log("retorno");
        this.targetEvt = result.target;
        this.amount = result.sumAmount;
        console.log("amount: ", this.amount);
        this.currency = result.currencyEvt;
        console.log("currency: ", this.currency);
        this.error = undefined;
        this.loadChart();
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        this.targetEvent = undefined;
        this.error = error;
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

  config = {
    generateGradient: true,
    pointer: {
      length: 0.5,
      strokeWidth: 0.05,
      iconScale: 1.0
    },
    // static labels
    staticLabels: {
      font: "14px sans-serif",
      labels: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      fractionDigits: 0
    },
    // static zones
    staticZones: [
      { strokeStyle: "red", min: 0, max: 0 },
      { strokeStyle: "orange", min: 0, max: 0 },
      { strokeStyle: "yellow", min: 0, max: 0 },
      { strokeStyle: "green", min: 0, max: 0 }
    ],
    // the span of the gauge arc
    angle: 0,
    // line thickness
    lineWidth: 0.2,
    // radius scale
    radiusScale: 1,
    // font size
    fontSize: 40,
    // if false, max value increases automatically if value > maxValue
    limitMax: false,
    // if true, the min value of the gauge will be fixed
    limitMin: true,
    // High resolution support
    highDpiSupport: true
  };

  loadChart() {
    console.log("loadChart() called");
    console.log(isTargetSpexInitialized);

    if (this.targetEvt == null || this.targetEvt === 0) {
      this.isTargetSpexInitialized = false;
      console.log("condition is true");
      this.targetEvt = 0;
      if (this.amount > 0) {
        this.sumOppsNotZero = true;
        this.currencyEvt = this.currency;
        this.sumOpps = this.amount.toLocaleString("en-GB");
      }
      return;
    }

    this.isTargetSpexInitialized = true;

    this.totalTarget = this.targetEvt.toLocaleString("en-GB");
    this.currencyEvt = this.currency;

    // staticLabels
    this.config.staticLabels.labels[1] = this.targetEvt / 4;

    this.config.staticLabels.labels[2] = this.targetEvt / 2;
    this.config.staticLabels.labels[3] = (this.targetEvt * 3) / 4;
    this.config.staticLabels.labels[4] = this.targetEvt;

    // staticZones
    this.config.staticZones[0].max = this.targetEvt / 4;

    this.config.staticZones[1].min = this.targetEvt / 4 + 1;
    this.config.staticZones[1].max = this.targetEvt / 2;

    this.config.staticZones[2].min = this.targetEvt / 2 + 1;
    this.config.staticZones[2].max = (this.targetEvt * 3) / 4;

    this.config.staticZones[3].min = (this.targetEvt * 3) / 4 + 1;
    this.config.staticZones[3].max = this.targetEvt;

    Promise.all([loadScript(this, gaugechart)])
      .then(() => {
        let target = this.template.querySelector("#spex canvas");
        console.log(target);
        Gauge.prototype.paddingBottom = 0.3;
        let gauge = new Gauge(target).setOptions(this.config);
        console.log(gauge);
        gauge.maxValue = this.targetEvt;
        gauge.setMinValue(0);
        gauge.animationSpeed = 32;
        gauge.set(this.amount);
        if (this.amount > this.targetEvt) {
          // this.config.staticLabels.labels[4] = this.amount;
          this.config.staticZones[3].max = this.amount;
        }
        this.percentage = ((this.amount / this.targetEvt) * 100).toFixed(1);
        this.chartInfo = `${this.currency} ${gauge.value.toLocaleString(
          "en-GB"
        )} (${this.percentage}%)`;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        this.dispatchEvent(
          new ShowToastEvent({
            title: "Error loading gauge.js",
            message: error.message,
            variant: "error"
          })
        );
      });
  }
}
```

Comment: I am slightly confused what you are doing here. Did you just create a new controller js file without a template? Is it in the same package as the gaugeChart component? I do not see anything that would call that other controller. You need to have it in the same controller or create an entire separate component.

Comment: I just create a new controller js file without a template. It is in the same package as the gaugeChart component.

CyberJus, I would not like to create an entire separate component, because the second gauge chart (the right one) needs to be in the same component of the left gauge chart.

I am new to the LWC and Salesforce technologies. My internship is about Apex, LWC and Lightning Experience. ^^

Comment: I fixed it! Thanks anyway, CyberJus! =D 

What I do now with my question?

Comment: I think you want to look into component structure. If you want to use the same guage chart component twice, you create 1 gauge chart component and then you can have 1 containing component that uses your gauge chart component twice.